# Figure out if an instance of Object is DataContract serializable in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I was reading the [reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx) on what types are serializable by WCF and it is ambiguous on what types are automatically KnownType and does that are not. Can anyone shed some light on that? For example, if my DataContract has a member of type Object, it will serialize fine if I pass a string, but not if I pass a Dictionary. The dictionary would need a KnownType, despite being mentioned as supported in that page. With that I have two questions:

1. So the question is, what are the automatic KnowTypes that WCF always use?
2. I need code that will figure out if an instance of object is KnownType by default. One solution would be to come up with an exhaustive list from the answer to 1 and than check the object against each one with a "obj is type" statement but that seems a bad implementation. Is there a smarter way?

EDIT:

This [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) lists the the types that are known by default. All primitives less DateTimeOffset plus XmlElement. So only two remains: How can I known if an Object is of primitive type?

EDIT 2:
typeof(obj).IsPrimitive will do most of the work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A known type is needed when only the base type is visible in the operation contract signature but some derived type could be returned. Example:

```
[OperationContract]
BaseClass Foo();
```

and in the implementation:

```
public Foo()
{
    return DerivedClass();
}
```

where `DerivedClass` derives from `BaseClass`. So you need to specify this explicitly either at the `BaseClass` declaration:

```
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass))]
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass { }
```

or using the [`[ServiceKnownType]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) at the service contract declaration:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(DerivedClass))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    BaseClass Foo();
}
```

or using the config file:

```
<system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
        <declaredTypes>
            <add type="SomeNs.BaseClass, SomeAssembly">
                <knownType type="SomeNs.DerivedClass, SomeAssembly"/>
            </add>
        </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
</system.runtime.serialization>
```

---

UPDATE:

As the documentation states it you don't need this for primitive types:

> The following types built into the
>   .NET Framework can all be serialized
>   and are considered to be primitive
>   types: Byte, SByte, Int16, Int32,
>   Int64, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, Single,
>   Double, Boolean, Char, Decimal,
>   Object, and String.

Comment: You are at least partially wrong. KnownType serves other purposes as well. For example I get a serialization exception if I don't add KnownType for a Dictionary<string,string>. Also you did not reply both of my questions :-( I downvoted, but will take it back if you edit the answer to actually address my problems. Again, I adid not ask about what KnownType does.

Comment: That's strange about `Dictionary<string, string>`. I don't get any exception with it. Are you sure you are not talking about `IDictionary<string, string>` which is a different story.

Comment: Can you explain the downvote? `Dictionary<string, string>` is a perfectly serializable type by `DataContractSerializer`. Just create a new WCF application using the default template, change the return type of the automatically generated method `GetData` from string to `Dictionary<string, string>`, run and invoke the service. It works flawlessly.

Comment: Remember that I'm serializing an Object, that happens to be a Dictionary at runtime, thus the need for KnownType. So the question remains, are types that don't require KnownType in this case, and how to check if an object is of one of them?

Comment: What Object are you serializing? How does your operation contract looks like? As I explained in my answer every derived type that could be potentially returned by your method needs to be known, so if you method signature looks like `object GetFoo()`, then you should list all possible types so that they can be exposed by the WSDL. Every type that doesn't appear in your method signature needs to be known.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the difference between my scenario and the one you are referring to (having a member typed as Object vs typed as Dictionary)

Comment: So take a look at my second and third examples. You need to specify the possible derived types either with `[ServiceKnownType]` attribute or at your config file. You can't use `[KnownType]` because you can't modify the Object class. Also note that it is a bad design to have your service methods return `object`. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The reason it works with string is because it is a primitive type as the documentation states it.

Comment: This is the reference I'm looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx